# How to retain datatypes when importing data from Oracle to HDFS using sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

We are using sqoop to import data from Oracle to HDFS.
In HDFS we are creating an avro file.

Issue we are facing is that, date is being converted to long and all other datatypes are being converted to string.
Is there any way to preserve the datatypes, when importing data using sqoop?

Thanks

Comment: In sqoop command use --map-column-java Col_Name=Data_Type,Col_Name=Data_Type and list all the columns which has to be cast.

Comment: Thanks.This was helpful.

Comment: pls upvote if comment helpful